# How to add a space between the subtitle and a comma between some of the words?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

How would I add a space between the subtitle and a comma between some of the words? I'm using swift 3.

```
 override
public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!

    let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
    cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = selectedItem.subThoroughfare!  + selectedItem.thoroughfare!
    + selectedItem.locality! + selectedItem.administrativeArea! + selectedItem.postalCode!



    return cell
}
```

Comment: I also get a crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting crash is because you are force wrapping the optional property of `CLPlacemark`, also if you want to join address try something like this. Make array of `String?` with all optional property that you are currently trying to make address without `!` after that `flatMap` array to ignore the `nil` and then simply joined the array with separator `,`.

```
override public tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!

    let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
    cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
    let addressArray = [selectedItem.subThoroughfare, selectedItem.thoroughfare, selectedItem.locality, selectedItem.administrativeArea, selectedItem.postalCode].flatMap({$0})
    if addressArray.isEmpty {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "N/A" //Set any default value
    }
    else {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = addressArray.joined(separator: ", ")       
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank You It works... but how would I go about having it appear like this 123 example st. example city, CA, Example zip code

Comment: I click the check mark, sorry I'm new to This site.

Answer (score 0):

You are using forced unwrap on values and there is a possibility that one of the value is `nil` due to which you are getting the crash when code is trying to concatenate string to `nil` values.